# CakePHP 3 - How to still contain() soft-deleted entities?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, soft-delete

I have an `Orders` and a `Users` table, such that `Orders` `belongsTo` `Users`.

I want users to be able to soft-delete their account, so I added a deleted field and modified the delete method. The user info is needed for administrative purposes, hence no hard deletes.

I also overrode the default finder of `UsersTable` such that deleted users will not pop up in lists or as results of `Users->get()`:

```
public function findAll(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->where(['Users.deleted' => false]);
}
```

I am satisfied with the way it works, mostly that I now cannot forget to exclude deleted users as the default finder already does the job.

The problem is I still want to include the user when it is contained from an order:

```
$order = $this->Orders->get($id, ['contain' => 'Users']);
```

And apparently when using contain() `findAll()` is used, because this does not include the deleted user.

How can I still include the soft-deleted entities in a `contain()`?

Is it possible to set a different default finder for contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use the `finder` option for contain to specify which finder to use, like:

```
$this->Orders->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Users' => [
            'finder' => 'withDeleted'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

or modify the query directly:

```
$this->Orders->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'Users' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
            return $query->find('withDeleted');
        }
    ]
]);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Passing Conditions to Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)**

However *any* custom finder would circumvent your modified `all` finder, which shows a flaw in your approach, once a query uses a different finder, and doesn't also explicitly use the `all` finder, your conditions will not be applied, which you most likely wouldn't want to happen so easily.

A better approach would probably be to use the `Model.beforeFind` event/callback. Here's a basic, rather strict example that uses an options approach:

```
public function beforeFind(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \Cake\ORM\Query $query, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (!isset($options['findWithDeleted']) ||
        $options['findWithDeleted'] !== true
    ) {
        $query->where(['Users.deleted' => false]);
    }
}

public function findWithDeleted(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->applyOptions(['findWithDeleted' => true]);
}
```

This would ensure that only when the `findWithDeleted` option is present, and set to `true`, the condition would not be applied.

You might also want to have a look at plugins that can handle this, like for example **https://github.com/usemuffin/trash**.

Comment: Very cool, as always @ndm. Question: do you think it's generally better to make the exception for including or excluding deleted rows?

Comment: @Roberto Probably depends on what exactly the application is used for, but generally I'd say that making including deleted rows the exception is the safer, and therefore favorable approach.

Comment: Implemented this an it's beautiful. I specified a finder in the association to contain deleted rows by default.